# How to test react render in the dom

Tags: reactjs, jestjs

I'm trying to test with jest *InstanceClass* who takes a token and a dom element to render inside a component
but I got a empty element.
I think that it doesn't take the mock dom

I'm using:
react
jest
testing-library/dom
testing-library/react

````
  test("Init", () => {
    document.body.innerHTML = `<div id="app"></div>`
    const instanceClass = new InstanceClass(TOKEN);
    instanceClass.init(
      { DOMPreview: document.getElementById('app')}
    )
    expect(document.getElementById('app')).not.toBeEmptyDOMElement()
  });
});


class InstanceClass {

  init = ({ DOMPreview }) => {
    const root = createRoot(DOMPreview);
    this.reactNode = root.render(<MyCpmponent token={this.token} />);
  }
}```
````